# Whats the meaning of more while running a shell script :! scriptname | more

Tags: shell, unix, vi

What is the meaning of `more` while running a shell script (directly from VI editor)?

```
:! scriptname | more
```

Comment: [`more`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html) is a command to display info. So most probably this is executing the script and, instead of showing all its output, send it to `more` so you can browse through the output.

Answer (score 0):

The more is the command to display the file page by page.
More prints the output of the scriptname program with page by page.

Answer (score 0):

```
more <textfile>
```

The main information you need on `more` command is that it is being used to open big text files.

In continue it also depends on which mode you are going to use on it.

**Man Page Description**

> The more utility is a filter that displays the contents of a
>        text file on the terminal, one screenful at a time.  It nor-
>        mally pauses after each screenful. /usr/bin/more then prints
>        --More-- and /usr/xpg4/bin/more then prints file at the bot-
>        tom of the screen. If more is reading  from  a  file  rather
>        than  a  pipe, the percentage of characters displayed so far
>        is also shown.
>
> The more utility scrolls up to  display  one  more  line  in 
>   response  to  a  RETURN  character.  more  displays  another 
>   screenful in response to a SPACE character.  Other  commands  are
>   listed below.
>
> The page utility clears the  screen  before  displaying  the  next 
>   screenful of text. page only provides a one-line over-  lap between
>   screens.
>
> The more utility sets the terminal to NOECHO mode,  so  that  the 
>   output can be continuous. Commands that you type do not  normally show
>   up on your terminal, except for the  /  and  !  commands.
>
> The /usr/bin/more utility exits after  displaying  the  last 
>   specified  file. /usr/xpg4/bin/more prompts for a command at  the last
>   line of the last specified file.
>
> If the standard output is not a  terminal,  more  acts  just  like 
>   cat(1),  except  that  a header is printed before each  file in a
>   series.